# I have a json file with a strange format that I can't read on pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

The file have the caracter "b" at the start, never seen this before. Here's how the file looks like:
[JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxFW6.png)

Tried a lot of stuff but can't turn it into a dataframe.
pd.read_json() didn't work and json_loads() also.

Just want to get the json file into a dataframe.

File string:

b'{"Cost Center":"7F6600","ID Subtask":"A1","ID Task":"W8","Task":"OtC CS","Subtask":"Order to Bill"}\n{"Cost Center":"AU0408","ID Subtask":"D0","ID Task":"P0","Task":"Supply Chain","Subtask":"SC-ExtWH) CS&AH"}\n{"Cost Center":"BC0C6180","ID Subtask":"D0","ID Task":"P4","Task":"Supply Chain","Subtask":"SC(FG-ExtWH) CS&AH"}\n{"Cost Center":"CJ3101","ID Subtask":"A0","ID Task":"W8","Task":"OtC CS","Subtask":"Or to Bill"}\n{"Cost Center":"CJ61053B","ID Subtask":"A1","ID Task":"O5","Task":"Production","Subtask":"P(Corp.)"}\n{"Cost Center":"H1093","ID Subtask":"D0","ID Task":"P0","Task":"Supply Chain","Subtask":"SC(FG-H) CS&AH"}\n{"Cost Center":"IQSES61","ID Subtask":"A9","ID Task":"W8","Task":"OtC CS","Subtask":"Order to Bill"}'

Comment: Someone who doesn't understand Python created that file incorrectly.  Try using `s = ast.literal_eval(s).decode()`.  And, by the way, if you had included that file as text, as you are supposed to, I could have cut-and-pasted it and tried that solution myself.

Comment: And then call `json.loads()` on the result of that.

Comment: Do you have control of whatever wrote the file? That's where the bug is. `b'whatever'` is python's way of displaying a `bytes` object - binary data. Instead of writing binary data whatever created the file wrote python's display representation of that data.

Comment: I do not. The file is an output from AWS Glue Databrew job, that is suposed to generate a json file but instead gave me this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error... When reading the file from AWS S3 Bucket I was using:

```
data = obj['Body'].read()
```

changed it to

```
data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

and worked

Comment: Oh, got it. The confusion is that you said you were displaying a file when in fact you were printing `data` in the above sample. `data` has a `bytes` object, when you print it you get the funky `b'whatever'` and when you decode it , you get the real string. It helps to show your work in the question so we are not confused.

Comment: Understood, will do better next time. Thank you all!